# Como Pasar de un objecto con sub objectosJSON a MySQL

Tags: php, json

Hola tengo un problema el día de hoy y es que cuando aprendí a hacer una api la DB la hice en un archivo JSON para no complicarme la vida.
Ahora que quiero importar la DB a MySQL no me deja ya que los objetos tiene sub-objetos

aquí un ejemplo:

```
"GatoID2":{
    "correo" : "gatofacha@maildrop.cc",
    "nombre": "Gato Fachero",
    "Nombre_usuario": "gatofacherito22",
    "Seguridad": {
        "Password" : "1234",
        "ID": "92648",
        "UUID" : "0c5648b2-d78b-4a86-a2eb-85038d7aa002"
    },
    "Extras": {
    "Perfil_IMG": "images/92648.png",
    "banner" : "images/92648Banner.png",
    "Color" : "#1c5050"
    },
    "Phone_Numbers": {
        "Default" : "111 - 1111 - 111",
        "Secondary" : "555 - 6643 - 555"
    }
}
```

me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de pasar todo eso a una tabla en MySQL o tengo que hacer tablas aparte para los sub-objetos?

Comment: Los objetos los puedes recorrer como te apetezca e ir rellenando las tablas de la base de datos que necesites.  Define bien cómo quieres las tablas, dados los datos que quieres guardar, y aclárate si quieres una tabla, dos o dos mil, y luego recorre el objeto para hacer las inserciones de los registros como creas conveniente.  En resumen, el objeto no condiciona como debe ser la base de datos, eso lo condicionas tu segun tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no existe algo Listo para usar, pero si se puede; en el sitio en ingles presentan esta posible solucion: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14935160/17161735)

> Pieza de código simple para crear una tabla mysql e insertar valores
> desde cualquier variable JSON. Este es un truco rápido... verifique
> los tipos de campo, etc. :) Probablemente haya mejores formas, pero
> esta funciona y ya me ha ahorrado horas en la nomenclatura manual de
> campos
>
> Esto se puede modificar para crear una tabla de relaciones que maneje
> objetos también. Ahora, está hecho para material JSON formado por
> matriz y no para objetos, es decir, matrices en matrices.

```
    <?php
        
        JSON_to_table($place_your_JSON_var_here_please);
        
                function JSON_to_table($j_obj, $tblName = "New_JSON_table_" . time()){
                $j_obj = json_decode($your_JSON_variable, true);
                if(!mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $tblName . "'"))){ 
                    $cq = "CREATE TABLE ". $tblName ." (
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";
                    foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                        $cq .= $j_arr_key . " VARCHAR(256),";
                    }
                    $cq = substr_replace($cq,"",-1);
                    $cq .= ")";
                    mysql_query($cq) or die(mysql_error());
                }
                
                $qi = "INSERT INTO $tblName (";
                reset($j_obj);
                    foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                        $qi .= $j_arr_key . ",";
                    }
                    $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
                $qi .= ") VALUES (";
                reset($j_obj);
                    foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                        $qi .= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "',";
                    }
                $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
                $qi .= ")";
                $result = mysql_query($qi) or die(mysql_error());
            
            return true;
                }
```

Tambien hay otra opcion que seria usar el mismo Json Como base de datos:
El sofá de [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) almacena su JSON "tal cual" sin que tenga que realizar ningún procesamiento.

Comment: tambien podria convertir el objecto en una matriz y poder importarlo mas facil o no?

Comment: una matriz es igual a un array; solo cambia el idioma, es lo mismo; entonces la opcion uno hace eso...

Comment: vale entiendo voy a implementarlo aver que pasa

Comment: @GatoFachero te sirvio?

Comment: Si bro muchas gracias